# Parsing JSON in Google Scripts

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am trying to parse a JSON object in Google Scripts but I can't seem to get it to work.

The JSON I am trying to parse looks like this

```
{  
 "keywords":[  
  {  
     "c":0.015165274822976534,
     "monthly":[  ],
     "kw":"handstand",
     "n":60500,
     "sb":0.3
  }
  ],
  "not_found":[  

]
 }
```

I can't seem to access any of the values within the object. If I use `JSON.parse()` it seems to create a non-JSON object.

```
  var response =  '{"keywords":[{"c":0.015165274822976534,"monthly":[  
  ],"kw":"handstand","n":60500,"sb":0.3}],"not_found":[]}'

  var obj = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log(obj);
```

Returns

```
{keywords=[{c=0.015165274822976534, monthly=[], kw=handstand, n=60500, sb=0.3}], not_found=[]}
```

This doesn't validate.

If I try to work with that anyways this happens

```
  var response =  '{"keywords":[{"c":0.015165274822976534,"monthly":[  
  ],"kw":"handstand","n":60500,"sb":0.3}],"not_found":[]}'

  var obj = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log(obj.keywords.n)
```

Returns `undefined`

If I don't use `JSON.parse` and just work with the original `response` object I get the following:

```
  var response =  '{"keywords":[{"c":0.015165274822976534,"monthly":[  ],"kw":"handstand","n":60500,"sb":0.3}],"not_found":[]}'

  Logger.log(response.keywords);
```

I get `undefined`

I'm not really sure where I am going wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ``n`` is in an array. So you can retrieve the value of ``n`` by ``Logger.log(obj.keywords[0].n)``. When you want to use your JSON object as an object at the script, please use ``var response = {"keywords":[{"c":0.015165274822976534,"monthly":[  ],"kw":"handstand","n":60500,"sb":0.3}],"not_found":[]};`` which doesn't enclosed in single quotes. By this, the object is parsed, and you can use ``Logger.log(response.keywords);``.

Comment: Tanaike basically have you the answer, to simplify what he said, consider that `keywords` is an **array** (not a JSON object) or drop the `[` and `]` after `keywords:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889223/parsing-json-in-google-scripts/49901134#comment86794744_49889223), your `n` property is a property of an object in the `keywords` array. So to log the values of n, you need to - after parsing the string to JSON - evaluate each object in `keywords`:

```js
var response =  '{"keywords":[{"c": 0.015165274822976534, "monthly": [ ], "kw": "handstand", "n": 60500, "sb": 0.3}], "not_found": []}'

var obj = JSON.parse(response);
// Log all values of n for each keyword:
obj.keywords.forEach(function (keyword) {
  console.log("Word: " + keyword.kw + ", times used: " + keyword.n);
});
```